# Handle Django Rest Framework permission when creating related objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions, django-permissions

The `has_object_permission` method of a Permission on DRF obviously does not get executed on Create, since the object does not exist yet. However, there are use cases where the permission depends on a related object. For example:

```py
class Daddy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Kiddy:
    title = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    daddy = models.ForeignKey(Daddy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If we only want to allow the owner of `Daddy` to create `Kiddy` of that `Daddy`, we would have to validate that somewhere.

I know this a really common discussion, also mentioned on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782778/django-drf-permissions-on-create-related-objects) and in many many more. It is also discussed on [DRF GitHub itself](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/7446/) where a docs update is done for that purpose, and referring to DRF docs it solves the problem [here with the following sentence](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#limitations-of-object-level-permissions):

> ... In order to restrict object creation you need to implement the permission check either in your Serializer class or override the perform_create() method of your ViewSet class.

So, referring to DRF docs, we could do one of the following solutions:

```py
class KiddySerializer(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    validate_daddy(self, daddy):
        if not daddy.owner == self.context['request'].user:
            raise ValidationError("You cannot create Kiddies of that Daddy")

        return daddy
```

or

```py
class KiddyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if (self.request.user != serializer.validated_data['daddy'].owner)
            raise ValidationError("You cannot create Kiddies of that Daddy")
        
        serializer.save()
```

Now, there is a problem which also brings up my question. What if I care about the information that is being shared to the user on an unauthorized request. So, in the cases where the `Daddy` does not exist, the user will get:
`Invalid pk \"11\" - object does not exist` and in the cases that the object exists but the user does not have access, it will return `You cannot create Kiddies of that Daddy`

I want to show the same message in both cases:

```
The Daddy does not exist or you don't have permission to use it.
```

It can be possible if I use a PermissionClass like below:

```py
class OwnsDaddy(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not Daddy.objects.allowed_daddies(request.user).filter(pk=request.data['daddy']).exists():
            return False
```

this will also work, but since the permissions are validated before serializer, if the ID of daddy passed by the user is incorrect (let's say string), a 500 error will be caused. We can prevent that by a try-except clause, but still it doesn't feel right.

So, at the end. What would be a good approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating custom field relation was the right approach for my case.

```py
from apps.models import Daddy
from rest_framework.serializers import PrimaryKeyRelatedField

class DaddyRelatedField(PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    default_error_messages = {
        "required": _("This field is required."),
        "does_not_exist": _("The Daddy does not exist or you don't have permission to use it."),
        "incorrect_type": _("Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received {data_type}."),
    }

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.read_only:
            return None
        queryset = Daddy.objects.all()
        return queryset.allowed_daddies(self.context["request"].user)
```

and then on serializer

```
class KiddySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    daddy = DaddyRelatedField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Validate in your serializer instead of view. You can validate a particular field in `validate_<field>` or as a whole in `validate` function

```
class YourModleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_field(self, value):
        return value
        
    def validate(self, attrs):
        validated_data = super().validate(attrs)
        return validated_data
```